How to get email received date using Office365-REST-Python-Client
Using this library I have been able to get the subject, sender, body, and attachments of all emails in an inbox but I cannot figure out how to get the received dates /sent dates of an email.
messages = client.users[*emailremoved*].messages.select(["subject", "body", "receivedDateTime"]).top(50).get().execute_query()


emails = []
excluded_senders = [*emailremoved*]

for message in messages:
    sender_email = message.sender.emailAddress.address
    if sender_email not in excluded_senders:
        email = {
            "Subject": message.subject,
            "Sender": f"{message.sender.emailAddress.name} <{sender_email}>",
            "Body": parse_html_to_json(message.body.content),
            "Attachments": [],
            "Date": message.receivedDateTime,

        }

And here is my error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cf36cf3304fd> in <module>
     39             "Body": parse_html_to_json(message.body.content),
     40             "Attachments": [],
---> 41             "Date": message.receivedDateTime,
     42 
     43         }

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'receivedDateTime'


Try message.ReceivedTime
